# Host name shows different when I try to connect to mysql database?

Tags: java, mysql, windows, networking

My computer credentials are :
Full computer name : AIS127.ABC.com

Domain: ABC.com

I have my entry in Users table to connect to mysql.
like :
 **host : ais127.ABC.com
 user: root**

I am getting following exception when I connect to mysql:

java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Access denied for user **'root'@'ais126.ABC.com'** (using password: YES))
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:2195)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1945)
    at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.getConnection(BasicDataSource.java:1412)
    at common.DBManager.getConnection(DBManager.java:80)
    at common.DBManager.getRecCSVInfo(DBManager.java:238)

Comment: You possibly have multiple network interfaces and you're connecting from an internal network, which has a different host name configured...?

Comment: Yes,I am connecting from internal network but nobody's host name configured differently.now 'root'@'ais126.ABC.com' this is my colleague host name which was my previous hostname.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe check in the code and see if you have hard-coded it somewhere.

Comment: No I have not hard coded it anywhere in my code. But as of I remember my previous computer name was "ais126.ABC.com" and after some time it changed to "ais127.ABC.com"

Comment: Maybe if have you referred to your host as 'localhost' somewhere in the code it might be still returning as "ais126.ABC.com". Better to check that too.

Comment: Yes , I checked it but nothing is found like that.